# COM Elevation Moniker fails to elevate the server under Vista/Windows 7

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-7, com, windows-vista

I’ve created a local COM server that requires elevation and should be instantiated from inside a non-elevated process.

Using [MSDN's article on the COM elevation moniker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I’ve configured the server class following the specified requirements. The server was successfully registered in the HKLM hive.

The code sample:

```
procedure CoCreateInstanceAsAdmin(const Handle: HWND;
      const ClassID, IID: TGuid; PInterface: PPointer);
var
  rBindOpts: TBindOpts3;
  sMonikerName: WideString;
  iRes: HRESULT;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@rBindOpts, Sizeof(TBindOpts3));
  rBindOpts.cbStruct := Sizeof(TBindOpts3);
  rBindOpts.hwnd := Handle;
  rBindOpts.dwClassContext := CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER;  
  sMonikerName := 'Elevation:Administrator!new:' + GUIDToString(ClassID);
  iRes := CoGetObject(PWideChar(sMonikerName), @rBindOpts, IID, PInterface);
  OleCheck(iRes);
end;

class function CoIMyServer.Create: IMyServer;
begin
  CoCreateInstanceAsAdmin(HInstance, CLASS_IMyServer, IMyServer, @Result);
end;
```

When it comes to `CoGetObject(PWideChar(sMonikerName), @rBindOpts, IID, PInterface)` I get the UAC screen and confirm running the server as admin. However, `OleCheck(iRes)` returns: "The requested operation requires elevation" error.

From [that article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I’ve read about "Over-The-Shoulder (OTS) Elevation".

Is this the only way to get my server instance available for the non-elevated process? If so, when should `CoInitializeSecurity` be called on the server?

---

**Complete registration details**

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID
    {MyServer CLSID}
        (Default) = IMyServer Object  
        LocalizedString = @C:\Program Files (x86)\MyServer\MyServer.exe,-15500  
    Elevation
        Enabled = 0x000001 (1)  
    LocalServer32
        (Default) = C:\PROGRA~2\MyServer\MYSERVER.EXE  
    ProgID
        (Default) = uMyServer.IMyServer  
    TypeLib
        (Default) = {TypeLib GUID}  
    Version
        (Default) = 1.0  

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\Interface
    {GUID of IID_IMyServer}
        (Default) = IMyServer  
    ProxyStubClsid32
        (Default) = {Some GUID}  
    TypeLib
        (Default) = {TypeLib GUID}  
        Version = 1.0
```

Above are the only entries that exist in my registry after registering the server.

---

**Additional details**

Tried without success calling `CoInitializeSecurity()` implicitly + setting lunch permissions as advised using the following code:

```
function GetSecurityDescriptor(const lpszSDDL: LPWSTR; out pSD: PSecurityDescriptor): Boolean;
begin
  Result := ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorW(lpszSDDL, SDDL_REVISION_1,
    pSD, nil);
end;

function GetLaunchActPermissionsWithIL(out pSD: PSecurityDescriptor): Boolean;
var
  lpszSDDL: LPWSTR;
begin
  // Allow World Local Launch/Activation permissions. Label the SD for LOW IL Execute UP
  lpszSDDL := 'O:BAG:BAD:(A;;0xb;;;WD)S:(ML;;NX;;;LW)';
  Result := GetSecurityDescriptor(lpszSDDL, pSD);
end;

function GetAccessPermissionsForLUAServer(out pSD: PSecurityDescriptor): Boolean;
var
  lpszSDDL: LPWSTR;
begin
  // Local call permissions to IU, SY
  lpszSDDL := 'O:BAG:BAD:(A;;0x3;;;IU)(A;;0x3;;;SY)';
  Result := GetSecurityDescriptor(lpszSDDL, pSD);
end;

function SetAccessPermissions(hAppKey: HKEY; pSD: PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR): Boolean;
var
  dwLen: DWORD;
  iRes: LONG;
begin
  dwLen := GetSecurityDescriptorLength(pSD);
  iRes := RegSetValueExA(hAppKey, 'AccessPermission', 0, REG_BINARY, pSD, dwLen);
  Result := iRes = ERROR_SUCCESS;
end;

function SetLaunchActPermissions(hAppKey: HKEY; pSD: PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR): Boolean;
var
  dwLen: DWORD;
  iRes: LONG;
begin
  dwLen := GetSecurityDescriptorLength(pSD);
  iRes := RegSetValueExA(hAppKey, 'LaunchPermission', 0, REG_BINARY, pSD, dwLen);
  Result := iRes = ERROR_SUCCESS;
end;

procedure Initialize;
var
  pSD: PSecurityDescriptor;
  sSubKey: WideString;
  hAppKey: HKEY;
begin
  sSubKey := 'AppID\{GUID}';
  RegOpenKeyW(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, PWideChar(sSubKey), hAppKey);
  if GetAccessPermissionsForLUAServer(pSD) then
    if not SetAccessPermissions(hAppKey, pSD) then
      raise Exception.Create(Format('Access permissions aren''t set. System error: %d',
        [GetLastError()]));

  pSD := nil;
  if GetLaunchActPermissionsWithIL(pSD) then
    if not SetLaunchActPermissions(hAppKey, pSD) then
      raise Exception.Create(Format('Launch permissions aren''t set. System error: %d',
        [GetLastError()]));
end;

initialization
  TAutoObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, TMyServer, Class_IMyServer,
    ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);
  Initialize;
```

As a AppID GUID I tried to use both the same CLSID GUID of my server interface and a new generated GUID: result was the same.
`AccessPermission` and `LaunchPermission` values appeared at the specified place after server registering.

Also tried:

- Specifying `ROTFlags = 1` in the AppId key
- Building the server as 64-bit application

Additional registry keys/values I created manually:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\MyServer.exe]
@="MyServer"
"AppID"="{My GUID}"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{My GUID}]
@="MyServer"
"ROTFlags"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{My GUID}]
@="MyServer Object"
"AppID"="{My GUID}"
```

Comment: You really should not be writing to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` directly.  It is fine for reading, but for write you should use `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` instead.  MSDN says as much.  Aside from that, where and how do you call `CoInitializeSecurity()`?

Comment: Ok about registry key. Fixed that. According to "Over-The-Shoulder (OTS) Elevation" section `CoInitializeSecurity()` is called implicitly (please see the example with `SetAccessPermissions` code) and thus I never called that myself.

Comment: Have you tried calling it explicitally yet?

Comment: Yep, tried that. `CoInitializeSecurity()` returned `ERROR_SUCCESS`, however that didn't change the situation. Maybe it's also worth to mention that the server requires uiAccess = True when elevated (the client is not elevated).

Comment: A follow-up: `CoInitializeSecurity()` was called from inside `Initialize` procedure from my example after getting pSD the first time.

Comment: Did you see this comment in MSDN's UAC documentation: "Applications with the uiAccess flag set to true must be Authenticode signed to start properly. In addition, the application must reside in a protected location in the file system. \Program Files\ and \windows\system32\ are currently the two allowable protected locations." Are you following those guidelines?

Comment: Specifying UIAccess=true for the COM object will put it into an integrity level that is slightly above Medium, so only processes in an equal or higher integrity level (namely elevated or other UIAccess=true processes) will be able to access it.  Non-elevated processes run in a Medium or lower integrity level.  That would explain why you keep getting `ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED` in your non-elevated app.

Comment: Remy, yes my server is signed and put into the trusted location. About your last comment: I was sure that the elevation moniker would be intended for such purposes. Anyway, thank you for the huge help on this issue.

Comment: Did you put the signing certificate into the machine's trusted root store?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One mistake you are making is you are passing the RTL's global `HInstance` variable where `CoGetObject()` expects an `HWND` instead.  An `HINSTANCE` handle is not a valid `HWND` handle.  You need to use an actual `HWND` such as the `Handle` property of a `TForm`, or else specify `0` to let the Elevation Moniker choose a suitable window for you.

As for the `ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED` return value, all I can say is that your COM registration is likely incomplete somewhere.  Please show the complete registration details that are actually being stored in the Registry (not what your code thinks it is storing - what the Registry is actually storing).

`CoInitializeSecurity()` should be called when the server process begins running.

Comment: Remy, thank you. I've fixed the problem with `HInstance` variable. I provided the registration details in the first post.

Comment: You have created a 32-bit COM server running on a 64-bit OS. Have you tried creating a 64-bit version of your COM server so it does not get registered under the `Wow6432Node` tree anymore?  Aside from that, have you tried adding the `ROTFlags` value to your registration?  See the `Elevated Servers and ROT Registrations` section of the article. Lastly, is your client app running in a lower integrity level? If so, see the `COM Permissions and Mandatory Access Labels` and `CoCreateInstance and Integrity Levels` sections of the article.

Comment: I've appended more details to my original post. I tried to apply all advices, however the result didn't change. Still getting `ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED`.